# Understanding Page Response

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest, cors, httprequest

I am trying to understand how the whole CORS policy works. To explain my confusion, let me give you an example:

```
$.get("https://www.google.com", function(response) { alert(response) });
```

The above request will return with the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/. Redirect from 'https://www.google.com/' to 'https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=TlqUWeGEH5HRXqW6utgI' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Now in order for that to work, google would have to white-list `https://fiddle.jshell.net`.

Now, if I were to try the same thing on a restful API page, that will work. My question is really simple, Why?

Trying to analyze this, I tried hitting an API and analyzing its response:

https://apigee.com/console/bing?req=%7B%22resource%22%3A%22web_search%22%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22query%22%3A%22sushi%22%2C%22sources%22%3A%22web%22%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%7B%22format%22%3A%22json%22%7D%2C%22headers%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22body%22%3A%7B%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22%7D%7D%2C%22verb%22%3A%22get%22%7D

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Date:
Wed, 16 Aug 2017 14:31:32 GMT
Content-Length: 266
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Apigee Router
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

I came to conclusion that it must be the headers. Specifically I belive that it is this header: `Content-Type: application/json;` But I don't know for sure, I am trying to understand this and hoping somebody here can explain to me.

Comment: I don’t know what “try the same thing on a restful API page” means but the gist of it is that by default browsers block your frontend JavaScript code from being able to access responses from cross-origin requests your send with XHR or the Fetch API or Ajax methods from Javascript libraries—unless the server the requests are being sent indicates it opts-in to receiving such requests. And the way that servers indicate that are opting in is by sending the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header in their responses.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS is the best place to start if you want to read up on how the CORS protocol works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did 2 tests: running your code `$.get("https://www.google.com", function(response) { alert(response) });` snippet from the console and requesting `https://www.google.com` from https://apigee.com/console/others

I think what happens in the 1st case is the fact that the request is done from the client, next request headers are sent:

```
:authority:www.google.com
:method:GET
:path:/?_=1502896196820
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
origin:https://stackoverflow.com
referer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717044/understanding-page-response
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3187.0 Safari/537.36
x-chrome-uma-enabled:1
x-client-data:CJG2yQEIo7bJAQiMmMoBCKudygEIs53KAQjRncoBCKiiygE=
```

Since Google does not reply with `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'` - client, and in the request I have `origin:https://stackoverflow.com`, Chrome in my case throws CORS error.

In the 2nd test, using https://apigee.com/console/others and requesting `https://www.google.com` , apigee.com seems to overwrite headers and sends:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host:
www.google.com
X-Target-URI:
https://www.google.com
Connection:
Keep-Alive
```

Also, from DEV console, I can see it does server to server call so no client involved in throwing CORS, thus I am getting the responses with Google page.

**UPDATE:**

Regarding JSON API requests, here is some interesting info from [Google CloudPlatform](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin) about CORS

> Note: CORS configuration applies only to XML API requests. For JSON
>   API requests, Cloud Storage returns the Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>   header with the origin of the request.

Thus, if the request is performed from the client, a client should not throw CORS errors since it gets Access-Control-Allow-Origin with the same origin it sent.

However, different APIs and clients might process requests differently. Thus, sometimes Firefox throws CORS while Chrome does not.

Comment: Please correct me if I misunderstood. You are saying that in your first test because it was a client based request it did not work. The second attempt worked because it was a server based request. With that in mind, my question is targeted towards client requests only. When you hit any API, even from javascript (client initiated) you get json results back. I'm trying to understand why that works, versus trying to get an html page where it won't work.

Comment: @Bojan I updated my answer with the example from Google cloud platform, maybe it will shed some light on the JSON based APIs requests.

Comment: In essence, I was correct to assume that the header `Content-Type: application/json;` is the reason why my client request would work. Because json type requests will not be blocked by CORS?

Comment: IMHO, I think it really depends from the API provider and which headers it sends back to the client. For example, public APIs might want to allow requests from various origins, while enterprise API will send back only specific origin to make sure only allowed domain can do requests. Thus, even if enterprise API might be public (no auth needed) if you're requesting it  with `Content-Type: application/json` from randomdomain.com - your client will still throw CORS since it will get origin mismatch. Does it make sense?

Comment: Ok so basically you are saying that all public API's will have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `*`. Is this correct? If so, doesn't it open doors to XSS attacks?

Comment: I am not saying that all public APIs will set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` As an example, check my answer -  "...Cloud Storage returns the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the **origin of the request** ". I am saying that each API is differently designed and it's up to DEV team / Business request to decide which headers to send back to the client.